# Problem with Stokes' theorem

Tags: stokes-theorem

I have read somewhere that the the integral of the exterior derivative of a one form gives zero by Stokes’ theorem, e.g.,

$$
\int_M d(f_i dx^i) =0  \qquad\text{for} \qquad f_i\in C^\infty(M)\,.
$$

But why?

Comment: Is $i$ a fixed index or do you mean something more general like $f_i \, dx^i$ with an implicit sum using Einstein summation notation?

Comment: @PratyushSarkar See the edited version.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the form you are integrating, I assume $M$ is a 2-manifold. By Stokes' theorem we get

$$
\int_M d(f_i \, dx^i) = \int_{\partial M} f_i \, dx^i.
$$

Now, what you have probably seen is that the last expression evaluates to zero when $M$ is a manifold without boundary, i.e., $\partial M = \varnothing$. This holds in general for any integral of an exact form over a n-manifold without boundary.

Comment: Yes, but it is not given whether the manifold is boundaryless or not. Why should the manifold be a 2-manifold?

Comment: @Immanuel Because you should integrate over a top form, i.e. a $n$-form. Mostly manifolds are considered without boundary and if the manifold admits a boundary, one usually writes *manifold with boundary* for clarity.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek I still don't understand why $M$ should be a 2-manifold! I think $M$ can be higher dimensional.

Comment: @Immanuel Because integrals are usually defined only for $n$-forms on $n$ dimensional orientable manifolds. And your integrand is a $2$-form. The manifold should be without boundary because otherwise what you read is not true. Quite often manifolds are only defined for the case without boundary and as TheGeekGreek mentioned, often manifolds without boundary are simply called manifolds.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar If we integrate this in a 3-dimensional manifold, then according to what you say, does the integral vanish? If yes, I think, this is what the author meant.

Comment: @Immanuel But you can't integrate a $2$-form on a $3$-manifold; there is no obvious definition for doing that.